# BIOS as bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I am considering installing Windows next to Ubuntu. Ubuntu is installed on a small-ish ssd, and I would like to keep it clean.

Can windows be installed on a second hard drive? Can I use the bios as an bootloader, switching between the two bootable drives?

I have not found anyone using this setup on the internet. There are lots of posts on the impossibilities of installing windows on an external hard dive though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, generally you can tell your bios which drive to boot, though how to do so depends on your bios.  So you can install each OS on its own drive, and change which drive the bios boots to toggle between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, technically, Windows can be installed on a second HDD.

The BIOS is on a special chip on your computers mobo, so the location won't be changed when you add a new HDD.

See, when your computer detects multiple OSs at boot, it'll show a black screen that lets you choose which OS you want to use.

I don't really understand what you mean by using the BIOS as the bootloader though.

Good luck.